# 3com switch has been set to forwarding state

Tags: 3com

i receive this error on the 3com switch syslog.

```
Oct  4 10:25:25:367 2013    MSTP    Information MSTP_FORWARDING Instance 0's port GigabitEthernet1/0/37 has been set to forwarding state.
Oct  4 10:25:25:352 2013    IFNET   Error   LINK_UPDOWN GigabitEthernet1/0/37 link status is UP.
Oct  4 10:25:19:545 2013    IFNET   Error   LINK_UPDOWN GigabitEthernet1/0/37 link status is DOWN.
Oct  4 10:15:52:389 2013    IFNET   Error   LINK_UPDOWN GigabitEthernet1/0/23 link status is DOWN.
Oct  4 10:15:46:377 2013    MSTP    Information MSTP_FORWARDING Instance 0's port GigabitEthernet1/0/35 has been set to forwarding state.
Oct  4 10:15:46:362 2013    IFNET   Error   LINK_UPDOWN GigabitEthernet1/0/35 link status is UP.
Oct  4 10:15:14:251 2013    MSTP    Information MSTP_FORWARDING Instance 0's port GigabitEthernet1/0/23 has been set to forwarding state.
Oct  4 10:15:14:236 2013    IFNET   Error   LINK_UPDOWN GigabitEthernet1/0/23 link status is UP.
Oct  4 10:15:12:433 2013    IFNET   Error   LINK_UPDOWN GigabitEthernet1/0/23 link status is DOWN.
Oct  4 10:06:28:139 2013    IFNET   Error   LINK_UPDOWN GigabitEthernet1/0/35 link status is DOWN.
Oct  4 10:06:11:916 2013    MSTP    Information MSTP_FORWARDING Instance 0's port GigabitEthernet1/0/4 has been set to forwarding state.
```

should i leave it or configure something?.thanks

Comment: Can you paste other logs?

Comment: the forwarding state messages just mean that spanning tree calculation has completed and that path was found not to contain any loops, so the port is set to forwarding.  If there where loops MSTP would put it into a blocking state

Comment: can it be that you have a cabel loop on your switch? I get this error when I try to check if the management site show error signs for when I do get a loop in the system

Answer (score 2):

Which part are you not sure about?

The MSTP messages are informational only saying that the port has entered the MSTP Forwarding state. This has happened because the port has come UP (ie, cable connected)

I'm not sure exactly why 3com would log the port going up/down as an error message, but it's telling you that a cable was (un)plugged (oe switch port administratively enabled/disabled on one end of the link). Do you expect these messages? (ie, was someone plugging/unplugging cables at the time?). If not, then you most likely have a cabling issue that needs to be identifed and fixed (loose connector, faulty wiring etc).